# Exception Safe Code for Generic Stack Class

Tags: c++, exception, generics, c++11

I am trying to write a exception safe generic stack. This is what I have done so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>

class stk_exception:public exception 
{
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "stack underflow";
    }
} stk_ex;

template <class T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    node<T> *next;
};

template <class T>
class stack_generic
{
public:
    stack_generic() : _head(nullptr) {
    }

    void push(T x) {
        node<T> *temp(new node<T>());
        temp->data = x;
        temp->next = _head;
        _head = temp;
    }            

    void pop() {
        if (_head == nullptr) {
            throw stk_ex;                
        } else {
            node<T> *temp = _head;
            _head = _head->next;
            delete temp;
            return;
        }
    }
    T top() {
        T x = T();
        if (_head == nullptr) {
            throw stk_ex;                
        } else {
           return _head->data;
        }
    }

private:
    node<T> *_head;
};

int main()
{
    stack_generic<int> s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    std::cout << s.top();
    s.pop();
    std::cout << s.top();
    s.pop();
}
```

I could have used STL list/vector for RAII, but I want to work with raw pointers. So, when I wrap the head pointer in stack with unique_ptr, it throws a compilation error "no matching function for call unique_ptr, default_delete. What's wrong here? Can anyone suggest what should I do to make this class exception safe? Thanks!

EDIT:
Added exception handling for underflow.
defined seperate top and pop methods

Comment: 1. Please don't use "NULL" for C++ code, use "nullptr" instead. 2. The formatting of your code is like a business card. If it looks messy, it's the first impression of you.

Comment: which line? where's the unique_ptr?

Comment: The default copy constructor and copy assignment operator for `std::unique_ptr` has been deleted, as in they don't exist. In order to use `unique_ptr` you will need to use `std::move` instead of making copies.

Comment: @Flovdis: `nullptr` is only an option if the code only needs to compile on C++11 compilers. But in that case, I agree that nullptr is the better solution. Maybe another alternative is to check the C++ version and use `#define nullptr NULL` for older versions.

Comment: @celtschk the use of `unique_ptr` also requires C++11, and there is a C++11 tag on the question.

Comment: @YoungJohn: I thought unique_ptr had already been in TR1, but it turns out I was wrong. The C++11 tag I admittedly overlooked.

Comment: The code is compiling fine. But when I change the head pointer in stack class to unique_ptr, it's throwing compilation error. move semantics isn't working either. And can anyone suggest what should be done, to make the above class exception safe.

Comment: I'm slightly concerned about the "underflow" case in `pop` since it returns a default constructed version of `T` and not what is actually on top of the stack. Considering that the code is trying to be exception safe it can probably be implied that the error handling of choice is exception handling so it would be ideal to throw an exception in the case of an "underflow".

Comment: @celtschk For C++ code before the C++11 standard, you should use just the `0` literal as a null pointer. The `NULL` macro is a relict from C programming and is usually just used there. See the statement from Stroustrup here: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null

Comment: Some compilers give extra warnings if you use `NULL` in an integer context, therefore I strongly disagree that using `0` is the way to go. I see absolutely zero advantage of `0` over `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to use the `std::shared_ptr`. You could implement the class like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>


template <class T>
class node
{
public:
    node(T data, std::shared_ptr<node<T>> next)
        : _data(data), _next(next)
    {
    }

    T data() const
    {
        return _data;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<node<T>> next() const
    {
        return _next;
    }

private:
    T _data;
    std::shared_ptr<node<T>> _next;
};


template <class T>
class stack_generic
{
public:
    stack_generic()
        : _head(nullptr)
    {
    }

    void push(T x)
    {
        _head = std::make_shared<node<T>>(x, _head);
    }

    T pop()
    {
        if (_head == nullptr) {
            throw std::underflow_error("underflow");
        } else {
            std::shared_ptr<node<T>> temp = _head;
            _head = _head->next();
            return temp->data();
        }
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<node<T>> _head;
};


int main()
{
    stack_generic<int> s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    std::cout << s.pop();
    std::cout << s.pop();
}
```

Note the following things:

- Using of `using namespace std;` is bad practice.
- Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` for modern C++ programs.
- Use an exception for the underflow to create a defined behaviour.
- Use accessor methods on the node to create a read-only object.
- Use a constructor for the node.
- Using **for example** `std::shared_ptr` to automatically free data.

Comment: prefer `std::make_shared` instead of constructing the `shared_ptr` with `new`.

Answer (score 5):

The following implementation should be (almost) exception-safe:

```
void push(T x) {
    head = new node<T>{std::move(x), head};
}
T pop(void) {
    if (head) {
        T result{std::move(head->data)};
        auto old = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete old;
        return result;
    } else {
        cout << "underflow!";
        return T{};
    }
}
```

The only problem of this code is the `return result`. In general, this operation might throw an exception, and in this case, the caller sees an exception, but the stack was nevertheless changed.

You can avoid this problem by separating the function into two functions. The first function returns the top element, and the second function removes it.

Comment: +1 for the mention of separate `top` and `pop` methods. The use of a separate `top` and `pop` function is how `std::stack` avoids exactly that issue.